# Insert image in editor after upload

Tags: image, upload, sharepoint-2013, image-uploading, ckeditor4.x

I've managed to upload images through drag & drop to a SP 2013 library by intercepting the `paste` and `fileUploadrequest` events (+ added mandatory headers and used `/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(\'/sites/theSite/theLibrary\')/files/add(overwrite=true,%20url=\'aDynamicFilename.jpg\')` as the request's URL).

The problem with this approach is that even if the image is uploaded, the image is not inserted in the editor (no error). I'm not setting `config.uploadUrl` for this approach.

**Q#1:** Is there any step which I should go through after the image is uploaded? Like telling the CKEDITOR instance to insert the image?

Later on, I've noticed that if I'm setting the `config.uploadUrl` to the same URL as I'm using above, the editor inserts successfully the image. The problem is that, from my trials, the `config.uploadUrl` is initialized together with the CKEDITOR instance (therefore, can't be assigned dynamically for each image, in case that multiple images are dragged and dropped on the editor).

**Q#2:** Is there another way to configure the `uploadUrl` or maybe some other config property that would allow the custom upload to work and insert the image in the editor?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually made it work by following a similar approach as the on in this repo:

[RyanSiu1995/ckeditor-ImageUploader](https://github.com/RyanSiu1995/ckeditor-ImageUploader/blob/master/imageUploader/plugin.js)

1. Use a **FileReader** and start loading the image when it's pasted to the
   CKEditor
2. On the **fileReader**'s `onload` event, create a `img` element in the
   editor's `document` object with some opacity and with the **fileReader**'s
   Base64 string as the `src`
3. On the **fileLoader**'s `uploaded` event, remove
   the img and re-add it with the actual file's url (changing the src
   attribute on the `img` was not triggering the editor's change event, which I was hooking into,so I chose to replace the whole element)

Here's the relevant section from the `ckeditor-ImageUploader` plugin:

```
    fileDialog.on('change', function (e) {
        var fileTools = CKEDITOR.fileTools,
            uploadUrl = fileTools.getUploadUrl( editor.config, 'image' ),
            file = e.target.files[0],
            loader = editor.uploadRepository.create(file),
            reader = new FileReader(),
            notification,
            img;

    // verify
    if (!/image/i.test(file.type)) {
        notification = editor.showNotification( 'Please check the correct format.', 'warning' );

        setTimeout(function() {
            notification.hide()
        }, 2000);

        return false
    }

    loader.upload(uploadUrl);

    // preview image
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        img = editor.document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        img.setStyle('opacity', 0.3);
        editor.insertElement(img);
    }

    loader.on('uploaded', function(evt) {
        editor.widgets.initOn(img, 'image', {
            src: evt.sender.url
        });
        img.setAttribute('src', evt.sender.url);
        img.setStyle('opacity', 1);
    });

    loader.on('error', function() {
        img.$ && img.$.remove();
    });

    fileTools.bindNotifications(editor, loader);

    // empty input
    fileDialog[0].value = "";
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically visually resize dropped image in the ckeditor4. Often, the dragged image is too big in dimension. True, it is resizable, but the user needs to go all the way to right bottom corner to resize it. What I would like to have is: once the image is dropped, it automatically resize to max_width: 600px, and height changes accordingly. Is this possible? Thanks.